# If I were to write down "101" (as in the introduction to a course) in letters, how would I do it?

Tags: pronunciation, numbers, dates

At first I thought that "**101**" was a prononciation of "**One-Null-One**", but then I found out that someone had wrote it down as "**One-Ow-One**". I'm confused.

Also: when I hear people pronouncing years like "**1902**" pronouncing the first two numbers first, are they saying: "Nineteen-Null-Two"?

I would be grateful if you could also provide me with other examples in which the number "0" is pronounced differently than "zero".

PS: I am a non-native speaker.

Comment: *Null* sounds British English. Americans will say one-oh-one and nineteen-oh-two. The spoken use of *oh* (representing the letter *o*) is commonplace. Also, *oh* is used in telephone numbers: one-eight hundred, five five five seven six oh five. Or you could say/write zero. Also zip codes 10001 one triple oh one. *OED* on *oh*: 'The Arabic zero, 0; nought. Usually in combination with other numerals.'

Comment: Of course, it's unlikely that you would ever have a need to write it any way other than "101", regardless of how you speak it.

Comment: When reading out a long series of numbers (eg, a credit card number, or some sort of technical data thing), it's not unusual to say "zero" (though "oh" is also used, depending on the context).  "Null" or "nil" is never used for saying numbers in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree. Tobias, are you just asking out of curiosity? Or is there a situation that is having you write `101` in letters? I'm a native American English speaker, and can not recall ever seeing "Econ One Zero One", "Nineteen Null/Oh Two" etc. *If anything*, a year would just be "Nineteen Hundred and Two" or "Nineteen Eighty Four". But it's rare to fully write that out.

Comment: We say the letter 'O' for zero in speech all the time. Not Ow or Null. 1902 is pronounced as 19-O-2, see? Works for years, addresses, phone numbers, even credit card numbers as spoken, but not as written. You could always say the zero instead, but even if the 'course' is imaginary, we still say 'He said what? That's covered in Politeness One-Oh-One!"

Comment: I could see the use of writing out the words if one were writing dialogue and wanted to capture the style and manner of speech. Pilot speak would be the most obvious where one would write numbers out (though probably not saying 'oh' for zero).

Comment: One Oh One is the universal university pronunciation in the United States. Not only does it signify a university course number, it also signifies the introductory level of the course. Calc 101 (usually differential), English 101 (usually composition), Spanish 101 (for those who know no Spanish), etc.

Comment: "Null" is never used for saying numbers in British English, either. "Zero" would only be used instead of "Oh" in BrE in a technical context - for example reading out a mathematical equation, or the navigator of a ship or aircraft saying something like "steer three zero five degrees." British universities etc. don't necessarily follow the common US system for numbering courses, but "one oh one" is widely understood as "an introduction to a subject" in the UK.

Comment: @Clare What, British English from Azerbaijan? We don't use "null" to mean "zero" here.

Comment: @alephzero Quite right. +1 (Hadn't read your comment before posting my own ...)

Comment: @Clare That's it then, I found out what people say when they don't pronounce a "0" as "zero" in dates, courses etc... It was not "null", it was "oh". Thank you.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't need to write "101" in letters, no. My goal was to understand what people say when they don't pronounce "0" as "zero".
I thought it was "null", but it turns out it is "oh". I had never heard "oh" used that way before. :-)
I started my research after listening to someone saying "101" (referred to an introduction to something) and then quickly realized that I had heard that in other circumstances too. (I stumbled upon "One-Ow-One" looking for an answer).

Answer (score 1):

In letters, 101 is written:

> One hundred one.

However, for courses, "one oh one" is one hundred one times more common.

Those who work in customer service over the phone are trained to use "zero."  Everyone else almost always says "oh" for the zero.  This goes for phone numbers, product numbers, addresses, etc.  (American English)

Answer (score 0):

According to my new favorite site on the internet, Google NGram, "one oh one" is a pronunciation listed in books. Neither "one null one" or "one ow one" in any of their forms are significant enough to register. Of course, some also say "one hundred one" or "one hundred and one". Those have a much higher rating in NGram, but one must keep in mind that deals with literature, not pronunciation.

So clearly "one oh one" is the dominant pronunciation, if it's listed in books, more than your alternatives. In my experience as an English speaker, people always say either that or the variants of "a hundred and one".

Comment: I use Ngram Viewer too from time to time.
Thank you. This pronunciation of the number "0" is something I wanted to understand for quite some time now.